# Redirect All Search Links Containing - to + on Wordpress

Tags: search, tags, htaccess, post-content

I deleted all my wordpress **tags** via **phpmyadmin**, and most of my post content contains **tag links**, now I redirected all the **tag links** to **search** using .htaccess,

I.E

`example.com/tag/stack-exchange/` will be redirected to `example.com/search/stack-exchange/`

It worked fine on some links, but I notice that some of the links does not pull out post title due to the `-` sign on the search link url, If i replace the `-` with `+` it will find my post content (title), but if it is `-` sign on the link url its does not pull out my post content when it is searched.

Please I there any way I can redirect all the search urls containing `-` on the link url to `+`

I.e redirecting `example.com/search/stack-exchange/` to `example.com/search/stack+exchange/`

`.htaccess` is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file to replace all `-` with `+` that occur after the `/search/` path segment in the requested URL:

```
RewriteRule ^(search/[^-]*)-([^-]*-.*) /$1+$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^(search/[^-]*)-([^-]*)$ /$1+$2 [R=302,L]
```

The first `RewriteRule` loops (internally) until all except 1 hyphen has been replaced with `+`. The second `RewriteRule` triggers an external redirect, replacing the last hyphen. In your example, where there is only 1 hyphen then the redirect will occur immediately.

Change the 302 (temporary) redirect to 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - only after you have tested that it works OK.

**UPDATE:** If you have a problem with a rewrite loop (and consequently no redirect) when there are multiple hyphens (`-`) in the requested URL then you probably have an issue with PATH_INFO being appended to the target URL on each iteration of the loop. This can be fixed with the `DPI` (Discard Path Info) flag on the first `RewriteRule` directive. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(search/[^-]*)-([^-]*-.*) $1+$2 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^(search/[^-]*)-([^-]*)$ /$1+$2 [R=302,L]
```

The slash prefix on the first `RewriteRule` *substitution* is then not required.

Comment: Thanks alot, your code It worked, but if the link url contains more than 2 words, it will not redirect to the `+` permalink on the url.

**After your code,**

`example.com/search/stack-exchange/` redirects to `example.com/search/stack+exchange/`

but if the url contains links like `example.com/search/stack-exchange-help/` it will will NOT redirect to the `+` url.

Is there any Fix for this ?

Comment: You may need to add the DPI flag on the first `RewriteRule` directive if you are getting a rewrite loop (this seems to be somewhat dependent on the specific config of the site/server) - I've updated my answer. Or there may be a conflict with other directives in your `.htaccess` file, in which case please include your entire `.htaccess` file in your question (with these directives in-place).